# Convergence of the maximum

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

> Let there be a sequence of iid r.v.'s $\{X_{n}\}_{n\geq1} \sim U(0,1)$, defining another sequence as $Z_{n} = max\{X_{1}, ...,X_{n}\}$, show that $Z_{N} \xrightarrow[]{P}1$.

So my thoughts are,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z_{n} \leq a) = \mathbb{P}(\max\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\} \leq a) = \mathbb{P}(X_{1} \leq q, ..., X_{n} \leq a) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n} \leq a)^{n}
\end{align}
Now defining the convergence criteria and developing results $\forall \epsilon >0$,

\begin{align}
lim_{n \xrightarrow[]{} \infty} \mathbb{P}(\lvert Z_{n} -1\rvert > \epsilon) &= lim_{n \xrightarrow[]{} \infty} 1 -  \mathbb{P}(\lvert Z_{n} -1\rvert \geq \epsilon) \\
&= lim_{n \xrightarrow[]{} \infty}1-\mathbb{P}(-\epsilon \leq Z_{n}-1\leq\epsilon)\\
&= lim_{n \xrightarrow[]{} \infty}1-\mathbb{P}(1-\epsilon \leq Z_{n}\leq 1+\epsilon)\\
&= lim_{n \xrightarrow[]{} \infty}1-\epsilon^{n}I_{\epsilon \in[0,1]} -I_{\epsilon \in(1,\infty)} \\
&= 0  \quad \forall \epsilon >0
\end{align}
Therefore $Z_{N} \xrightarrow[]{P}1$.

I'd like to know if my line of thought is correct, I'm self-learning the theme. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are making it complicated. Note that $Z_n \leq 1$. Hence $P\{|Z_N -1|>\epsilon \}=P\{Z_n <1-\epsilon\} =(P\{X_1 <1-\epsilon \})^{n}=(1-\epsilon )^{n} \to 0$.

Comment: Indeed, your way is cleaner. But is my solution incorrect or just unnecessarily complicated? =)

Comment: Your solution is correct.